# Find/Colour Script for Google sheets, access variable outside loop not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'll make this one quick:

```
function FindDupes() {
  var currentSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = currentSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];

  var checkRange = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var values = checkRange.getValues();

  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 

    //remove full-stops
    var value = values[i].toString().replace(new RegExp("\\.", "g"), "").replace(new RegExp("\\#", "g"), "");

    if (value.indexOf(",") > -1) {
      var splitValues = value.split(",");

      for (var j = 0; j < splitValues.length; j++){
        var splitValue = splitValues[j].toString().replace(new RegExp("\\.", "g"), "");

        data.push(splitValue);
      }

    }
    else {
      if (value.length > 0){
        data.push(value);
      }
    }   
  }

  var findDupesRange = sheet.getRange("B:K");
  var findDupesRangeValues = findDupesRange.getValues();

  var colCount = findDupesRange.getNumColumns();
  var rowCount = findDupesRange.getNumRows();

  var r = 0;
  var c = 0;
  var d = 0;

  while (c < colCount) {
    while (r < rowCount) {
      while (d < data.length) {
              Logger.log(r);
        if(findDupesRangeValues[c][r] && findDupesRangeValues[c][r].indexOf(data[d]) > -1){
          findDupesRange.getCell(r+2, c).setBackground("#F17321");         
        }        
        d++;
      }      
      r++;
    }    
    c++;
  }
}
```

At the while loops section, when inside the "r" loop, I cannot access "c", and while in the "d" while loop, I can not access either "c" or "r" in Google Scripts API for Google Sheets. Why is this?

Log:

```
[17-12-19 16:27:21:523 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:523 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:524 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:525 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:526 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:527 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:527 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:528 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:529 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:529 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:530 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:531 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:532 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:533 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:533 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:534 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:535 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:535 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:536 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:536 SAST] 0.0
[17-12-19 16:27:21:537 SAST] 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why - but nested while loops just hang for me.

This example works for me, and I think accomplishes the same thing:

```
function looperExample() {
    for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
        for (var d = 0; d < 5; d++) {
            var r = 0;
            do {
                Logger.log("outer loop: " + c + " middle: " + d + " last: " + r);
                r++;
            } while (r < 5);
        }
    }
}
```

12/30/2017 - I'm updating my original answer above:

The following will compare the values in the first column with the rest of the cells in the sheet that have data, and color those cells if they are duplicates of values in the first column. 
I separated out the part that splits the values into a separate function:

```
function fixVals (a_values) {
    var data = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < a_values.length; i++) {
        var value = a_values[i].toString().replace(new RegExp("\\.", "g"), "").replace(new RegExp("\\#", "g"), "");
        if (value.indexOf(",") > -1) {
            var splitValues = value.split(",");
            for (var j = 0; j < splitValues.length; j++) {
                var splitValue = splitValues[j].toString().replace(new RegExp("\\.", "g"), "");
                data.push(splitValue);
            }
        } else {
            if (value.length > 0) {  data.push(value);  }
        }   }
  return data;
}

function ColorDuplicateCells() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
    var a_values = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    var data = fixVals(a_values);
    var data_lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
    var data_lastCol = sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn() - 1; // subtract the first col because it's the data

    var findDupesRange = sheet.getRange(1, 2, data_lastRow, data_lastCol);
    var findDupesRangeValues = findDupesRange.getValues();
    var col_RangeCount = findDupesRange.getNumColumns();
    var row_RangeCount = findDupesRange.getNumRows();
    Logger.log("a1 notation of range: " + findDupesRange.getA1Notation());

    for (var data_loc = 0; data_loc < data.length; data_loc++) {
        var data_currentVal = data[data_loc];
        for (var r_dataRow = 0; r_dataRow < row_RangeCount; r_dataRow++) {
            for (var c_dataCol = 0; c_dataCol < col_RangeCount; c_dataCol++) {
                var currentRangeVal = findDupesRangeValues[r_dataRow][c_dataCol];
                Logger.log("-------------------------------------------------------");
                Logger.log("data_currentVal we are checking against: " + data_currentVal);
                Logger.log("     r_dataRow: " + r_dataRow + " c_dataCol: " + c_dataCol + "  val found: " + currentRangeVal);
                if (data_currentVal === currentRangeVal) {
                    Logger.log("--------------------------------!!!!!!!!---found a match: " + data_currentVal);
                    findDupesRange.getCell(r_dataRow + 1, c_dataCol + 1).setBackground("#F17321");
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a go. It perplexed me yesterday - it seems like, each time you open a loop, you open a different scope - and variables no longer get tracked

Comment: What happens when you step through it with the debugger?

Comment: Your sample worked - my code is still kinda broken. I will still mark this since I wanted a solution to getting _something_ to iterate :)

Comment: This is the weird part. if you had a if statement in there to say, change a cell colour based on where your iteration is (column and row variables) - if *something or anything* matches an array at index d , it does nothing.

Remove the logger.log - script runs instantly
Add it back in, you can clearly see the timing difference that it is doing _somthing_ - which is logging .